# p:autoComplete with more than one category

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

How can I implement JSF primefaces autocomplete with more than one category? Model is `Location` and `City`. I would like to search city as well as location in a single `<p:autoComplete>` as in below example.

[image: Example]

```
   <p:autoComplete value="#{addEmployeeDetailsBean.selectedText}" completeMethod="#{addEmployeeDetailsBean.locatioAutoCompleteMethod}" maxResults="5"   var="theme" itemLabel="#{theme}" itemValue="#{theme}" forceSelection="true" />
```

Bean

```
   private String selectedText;
   public List<String> locatioAutoCompleteMethod(String query) {
    autoCompletedList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (autoCompletedList != null) {
        autoCompletedList.clear();
    }
        if (cityAutoList != null) {
        for (CityModel cityObj : cityAutoList) {
            if (cityObj.getCityName().toLowerCase().trim()
                    .startsWith(query.toLowerCase().trim())) {
                autoCompletedList.add(cityObj.getCityName());
            }}}
    if (locationDetailsList != null) {
        for (LocationModel locationObj : locationDetailsList) {
            if (locationObj.getLocationName().toLowerCase().trim()
                    .startsWith(query.toLowerCase().trim())) {
                autoCompletedList.add(locationObj.getLocationName() + ","
                        + locationObj.getCityObj().getCityName());
            }
        }
    }
    return autoCompletedList;
}
```

City Modal:

```
     public class CityModel implements Serializable{
    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "cityId", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long cityId;

@Column(name = "cityName")
private String cityName;
```

}

Location Modal:

```
public class LocationModel {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "locationId", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long locationId;

@Column(name = "locationName")
private String locationName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cityObjId")
private CityModel cityObj;

@Column(name = "pinCode")
private String pinCode;
```

}

Comment: add your code to the question!

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴠʏ: for single pojo my autocomplete works well.. i am working with two pojo modals with one autocomplete ...City modal has cityid and cityname as property  location has the locationid, locationname and  cityobj.

Comment: @JAVY: Have a look at that image ...' Bangalore' is an city, 'Whitefiels,Bangalore' is an location